# Disable Vim SnipMate brackets replacement

Tags: vim, code-snippets

In Vim, after I installed vim-snipmates, I want to use this snippet to auto complete brackets.

```
snippet (
    (${1})${2}
```

But, I encountered a problem, if I input things like this:

[image]

The last bracket is completed by the snippet when I input the first <kbd>(</kbd> and <kbd>tab</kbd>, and this time when I press <kbd>tab</kbd>, I want to add another <kbd>)</kbd> to the end and make things like this:

[image]

But, it turns out the Vim thinks I want to input a <kbd>)</kbd> to finish everything, so it replaces the last <kbd>)</kbd>, and there is still one <kbd>)</kbd> at the end of the line.

I want to know which plugin did this replacement and how can I disable it.

`.vimrc`

```
Bundle "MarcWeber/vim-addon-mw-utils"
Bundle "tomtom/tlib_vim"
Bundle "garbas/vim-snipmate"
Bundle "honza/vim-snippets"
```

I feel it's very hard to describe it.

Comment: Have you tried removing all of those plugins except for vim-shipmate and adding them back in one by one until the problem begins to reoccur?

Comment: @ebenezer I did that and it repeated, but I understand what happened now, the second < tab > didn't work like define but jump to the ${2}. Thank you for the reminding.

Comment: do you have an autoclose plugin, such as delimitmate or autoclose-pairs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second < tab > didn't work like define but jump to the ${2}

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a snippet plugin, say Snipmate, Neosnippet or Ultisnips, the job of **auto close** parens, brackets or quotes <kbd>)</kbd><kbd>}</kbd><kbd>]</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>'</kbd> is better suited for an autoclose plugin, such as [Delimitmate](https://github.com/Raimondi/delimitMate) or [autopairs](https://github.com/jiangmiao/auto-pairs).